# Can't add FTP Site (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5

I've got my IIS 7.5 running with the FTP role installed. When I right-click the site node in the IIS manager I don't see the option "Add FTP Site". What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the FTP Role Service. You can do this by modifying the Application Server role in Server Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you've not enabled this under your installed Windows components.  Fixing this is very easy.  **Go to your control panel and find the "Programs" page.**

Click on **"Turn Windows Features On/Off" and look for Internet Information Systems**.  Expanding that tab will probably result in an unchecked box for **"FTP Server".  Just check the box, let it install and you are all set!**

Comment: 2st problem I can see here - poster is setting up an FTP site. ;-)

Comment: This answer is for Server 2003.  MarkM is correct for Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Hadn't realized this changed with 2008, sorry about that.  Thank you to the the one who provided me with reputation points :)